# Filtering Rows from a from a resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select count(name),continent
from world
where population <= 25000000
group by continent
```

When I run the following Query on the world table the following results appeared

```
COUNT(NAME) ;   CONTINENT
===================================
26         ;    North America
**17       ;    Oceania**
7          ;     South America
41         ;     Europe
42         ;     Africa
24         ;     Asia
```

Again I have ran the following query

```
select count(name)
from world
group by continent
```

the following results appeared

```
COUNT(NAME) ;  CONTINENT
===================================
29       ;    North America
**17     ;        Oceania**
12       ;    South America
49       ;      Europe
54        ;     Africa
42     ;       Asia
```

Considering these as two tables I have tried to extract the rows which has common  `count(name)`

values I had run this query

```
select count(name),continent
```

from world
group by continent
having  count(name) in (
select count(name) from world where population <= 25000000 group by continent )

resulted in

```
COUNT(NAME) ; CONTINENT
================================
17         ;  Oceania   <--------- thought I will get only this row
42         ;  Asia
```

now again i had run this query

```
select count(name),continent from world where population <= 25000000 group by continent  having  count(name) in (select count(name) from world  group by continent )

COUNT(NAME) ;CONTINENT
===============================
17      ;    Oceania
42       ;   Africa
```

I have got issue of Asia and Africa coming in the Result set

but how can I Filter them too
Assume that I am using MY SQl

(Treat me as an absolute beginner and forgive me for bad editing can't help it)

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
SELECT count(name), continent FROM world
WHERE population <= 25000000 GROUP BY continent
```

You are selecting the number of countries with a population less than 250m. Oceania and Africa are included in these rows.

```
COUNT(NAME) ;   CONTINENT
===================================
26         ;    North America
**17       ;    Oceania**
7          ;     South America
41         ;     Europe
42         ;     Africa
24         ;     Asia
```

Next you execute:

```
HAVING count(name) in (SELECT count(name) FROM world GROUP BY continent)
```

I.e. only include rows where the number in COUNT(NAME) is found in the COUNT(NAME) column of your result set with no WHERE. `Oceania` has 17 in both result sets, so it's included. `Africa` has `COUNT(NAME)=42` in the first (WHERE) result set. Using your HAVING clause, it gets matched with `Asia` in your second result set.

Thus we show two rows:

```
COUNT(NAME) ;   CONTINENT
===================================
17       ;    Oceania
42         ;     Africa
```

This is probably what you want (note the added `WHERE`):

```
SELECT count(worldA.name) as cnt, worldA.continent FROM world worldA
WHERE worldA.population <= 25000000 GROUP BY worldA.continent
HAVING cnt in
    (SELECT count(worldB.name) FROM world worldB
    WHERE worldB.continent = worldA.continent
    GROUP BY worldB.continent);
```